# Is there a portable way to have a function use an arguments 'const' to be used for the return value?

Tags: c, constants, c11

When writing a function that returns part of a string, it may be useful to have it use the const value of an argument in its return value.

Take `strstr` in gnu-libc which uses C++ and `__asm` for example:

```
extern "C++"
{
extern char *strrchr (char *__s, int __c)
     __THROW __asm ("strrchr") __attribute_pure__ __nonnull ((1));
extern const char *strrchr (const char *__s, int __c)
     __THROW __asm ("strrchr") __attribute_pure__ __nonnull ((1));
....
```

Is there a portable way in C to have a function which uses the `const` value of an argument to define the `const` of the return value?

---

*Note, Of course its always possible to return an offset instead of the string its self as a workaround.*

Comment: Well, that example is C++... C++ has function overloading.

Comment: Right, but the question is about C, edited question to clarify this.

Comment: @Lundin gives a nice answer for C11, but have in mind that string literals in C are *not* const qualified, so it wouldn't help you with them.

Answer (score 3):

It might be possible with evil macro tricks. I won't even consider that. The only good solution requires C11 where you have `_Generic`, which can sense the type used at compile-time.

Example with some nonsense code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define strrchr(s,c)                      \
  _Generic((s),                           \
            char*: strrchr_s,             \
            const char*: strrchr_cs) (s,c)

char *strrchr_s (char *__s, int __c)
{
  printf ("Not constant: %s\n", __s);
  __s[1] = 'a';
  return __s;
}

const char *strrchr_cs (const char *__s, int __c)
{
  printf ("Constant: %s\n", __s);
  return __s;
}


int main (void) 
{
  char str[] = "Hello";

  (void)strrchr(str, 0);
  (void)strrchr((const char*)str, 0);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Not constant: Hello
Constant: Hallo
```

This is 100% standard and portable, assuming there is support for C11.

Comment: Since the standard text is ambiguous with respect to that, there maybe compilers that don't do array to pointer conversion for the selection expression. Therefore it might be better to have `&(s)[0]` instead of `(s)`.

Comment: @JensGustedt Hmm. That's a good point. Checking the standard and it just says "The controlling expression of a generic selection is not evaluated" which does indeed open up for different interpretations. However, if the passed parameter would be of array type, then the code wouldn't compile, as there is no default association present. It would perhaps better to let the compiler error appear and have the caller re-adjust the call to `&str[0]`.